# Как создать переменную int из выражения?

Tags: java, переменные

Можно ли сделать одну `int` переменную из `list.get(count-1))`

```
int mNumbers = (list.get(count-1));
```

не работает.

В коде это все работает, но так мне кажется не красиво.

```
mInfoTextView2.setText(list.get(count-1) + "");    

switch (list.get(count-1))
```

---

```
 public  ArrayList<Integer> list;
int i;
int maxQ = 20;
int selectQ = 10;
 int iCounter = 0;
int iArray[] = new int[selectQ]; // или сколько тебе там надо рандомных чисел, сюда закидаешь

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setHashList();
}

private void setHashList() {
    mInfoTextView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mInfoTextView2=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mInfoTextView3=findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 1; i < maxQ; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    mInfoTextView.setText(list.toString());

}

public void onClickNext(View view) {
    //int mNumbers = (**list.get(iCounter-1)**);

    mInfoTextView3=findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mInfoTextView2=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  //  mInfoTextView3.setText(list.get(list.size() - 1));
    Button mBut = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    i = iArray[iCounter];
    iCounter ++;
    if (iCounter == iArray.length) iCounter = 0;
    mInfoTextView2.setText(**list.get(iCounter-1**) + "");
    mInfoTextView3.setText((iCounter) + "");

    if (iCounter == selectQ-1) {mBut.setEnabled(false);}
    else {
        switch (**list.get(iCounter-1)**) {
            case 1: {
                Log.d(TAG, "ТУТ:1");

            }
            break;
            case 2: {
                Log.d(TAG, "ТУТ:2");
```

так все работает...вопрос как сделать из **list.get(iCounter-1** переменную int

Comment: А list это у вас что такое?

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> list;

Comment: Что значит _не работает_?

Comment: Тогда объясняйте как это _не работает_

Comment: Если написать так: `int mNumbers = (list.get(count-1));`, `mInfoTextView2.setText(mNumbers  + ""); `, `switch (mNumbers)` то все должно работать.

Comment: Такая ошибка ` Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
        at com.fl.testfragment.MainActivity.onClickNext(MainActivity.java:55)`

Comment: добавил код, посмотрите

Comment: Индекс не должен быть отрицательным - проследите за этим. То есть в выражении `list.get(count-1)` - `count` не имеет права быть меньше единицы и больше размера коллекции

Comment: @IgorDemo ArrayIndexOfBoundException - выход за границы массива (если перевести). Значит в какой-то момент Вы выходите за границы массива... (пытаетесь обратиться к 10-му элементу, когда массив содержит всего 9). Это же очевидно...

Comment: @ not a Programmer - это понятно,ведь -1 стоит, когда...не знаю как от минуса избавиться, обновлю код, может кто поможет....

Comment: @IgorDemo, проблема в этой строке `//int mNumbers = (**list.get(iCounter-1)**);`. Я не понимаю, зачем обращаться к _-1_-му элементу (так как `iCounter = 0`)? Чего Вы хотите добиться этой строкой?

Comment: Уберите этот злосчастный  -1 и всё получится.

Comment: В массиве например 5 чисел под позициям от 0 до 4, iCounter хоть = 0 но берет последовательно, числа с позиций 1-4, нулевую пропускает,  только iCounter-1 начинает брать значение с нулевой позиции массива....

Comment: Ничего там не пропускается - если задан `0` то будет взят элемент из нулевой позиции.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, если я правильно Вас понял:

```
    private int iCounter = 0;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void onClickNext(View view) {
        int number = list.get(iCounter);

        mInfoTextView2.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        mInfoTextView3.setText(String.valueOf(iCounter + 1));
        iCounter++;

        if (iCounter == list.size()) mBut.setEnabled(false);

        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                Log.d(TAG, "ТУТ:1");
                break;
            case 2: 
                Log.d(TAG, "ТУТ:2");
                break;
            // etc.
        }
    }
```